# Selective reading in of JSON objects

Tags: json, python-3.x

Let's assume that I have this JSON string (copied from [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-json))

```
{ 
  "sammy" : {
    "username"  : "SammyShark",
    "location"  : "Indian Ocean",
    "online"    : true,
    "followers" : 987
  },
  "jesse" : {
    "username"  : "JesseOctopus",
    "location"  : "Pacific Ocean",
    "online"    : false,
    "followers" : 432
  },
  "drew" : {
    "username"  : "DrewSquid",
    "location"  : "Atlantic Ocean",
    "online"    : false,
    "followers" : 321
  },
  "jamie" : {
    "username"  : "JamieMantisShrimp",
    "location"  : "Pacific Ocean",
    "online"    : true,
    "followers" : 654
  }
}
```

I need to **selectively** read in only objects/records that contain, say, Pacific in the key named location. How can I **NOT** read in other records, such as the ones with "Indian Ocean" and "Atlantic Ocean" as values for location? So far, all examples I can find read in the entire file.

Thank you very much for help, even the answer is "you just have to read in the whole thing"!

Comment: Why exactly are you so against reading the entire thing and then filtering it to remove the ones with the wrong ocean? It's much more difficult to read something like a JSON file in chunks, since you can't be sure how its structure is.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't read the file in and slice, you can do it by loop

```
selective_data = ['Pacific Ocean']
batch = []

for k, v in data.items():
    for ii, jj in v.items():
        if jj in selective_data:
            batch.append(v)
```

`df = pd.DataFrame(batch)`

```
            username       location  online  followers
0       JesseOctopus  Pacific Ocean   False        432
1  JamieMantisShrimp  Pacific Ocean    True        654
```

Comment: Thank you Kenan for answering the question. The problem is not reading in the the entire file. The problem is that the file contains information I should not know. If I can filter these objects out before reading them in, I can then read the file. Otherwise, I have to wait until the developers create a special file for me. I am trying to avoid the waiting.

Comment: Ok did you try my solution, it doesn't involve reading the whole file

Comment: Kenan, how would you initialize the variable data? What libraries would you include? Thanks.

Comment: data is the  `JSON string` you provided, i assume you did `json.load` from the `json` library

Comment: Kanan, what would you get if do print(data) before your for loops?

Comment: it would print the data? I'm not sure what are you expecting

Comment: The problem I need to resolve is not to load the entire JSON file. In the sample code, I should not read in any record where location is not "Pacific Ocean." Do you know a way of doing that? Thanks!

Comment: What you asking for is logically not possible. The only way to determine if a line contains `Pacific Ocean` it has to be read. So you can always see whats in the file. That kind of filtering should be done in the backend before the file reaches you

Comment: I was hoping there are some libraries that allow us to pre-process the JSON string and return a filtered subset. JSON-path is trying to do that, but on attributes only, not on objects. Thank you Kenan for your input.

Comment: what I wrote would be in the library since the library too would have to read the file.